# Loop Through Gridview Rows And Access Each Rows Element

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a Grid view control in my application. In the Grid views each row (Item Template) I have a checkbox control and a hidden field. Here the hidden fields get populated from database with  `'<%# Eval("IsChecked") %>'` . While on  rendering the gridview I want to loop through each row with jQuery and read the hidden fields value, if found the value is “False” (this is what returned from Data base True or False) then disable the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery to accomplish this. If you're using an `<asp:CheckBox />` control, just set the `Enabled` attribute to `Enabled='<%#Eval("IsChecked")%>'`.